# PyTest plugin using xmlrpclib fails with IOError: "unsupported XML-RPC protocol" on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, xmlrpclib

When running py.test using a plugin that loads xmlrpclib the test run fails with:

> INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   INTERNALERROR> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/_pytest/main.py", line 70, in wrap_session
>   INTERNALERROR> config.pluginmanager.do_configure(config)
>   INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py", line 267, in do_configure
>   INTERNALERROR> config.hook.pytest_configure(config=self._config)
>   INTERNALERROR> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py",line 421, in **call**
>   INTERNALERROR> return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
>   INTERNALERROR> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py",line 432, in _docall 
>   INTERNALERROR> res = mc.execute()
>   INTERNALERROR> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/_pytest/core.py",line 350, in execute
>   INTERNALERROR> res = method(**kwargs)
>   INTERNALERROR> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytest_marker_bugzilla-0.01-py2.7.egg/pytest_marker_bugzilla.py",line 94, in pytest_configure
>   INTERNALERROR> bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url=url)
>   INTERNALERROR>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/bugzilla/**init**.py", line 75, in **init**
>   INTERNALERROR>     c = getBugzillaClassForURL(kwargs['url'])
>   INTERNALERROR>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/bugzilla/**init**.py", line 26, in getBugzillaClassForURL
>   INTERNALERROR>     s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url)
>   INTERNALERROR>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/xmlrpclib.py", line 1215, in **init**
>   INTERNALERROR>   raise IOError, "unsupported XML-RPC protocol"
>   INTERNALERROR> > > IOError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol

I have verified that xmlrpclib will work with a simple test program, this program removes py.test from the picture.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xmlrpclib
import bugzilla
import sys
for i in sys.path:
    print i

url = 'https://bugzilla.redhat.com/xmlrpc.cgi'
u = ' '
p = ' '

try:
    proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url)
except(), e:
    print e
b = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url=url)
b.login(u,p)
bug = b.getbugsimple('12345')
print bug
```

The program above when executed returns as expected.  I am at a loss for what is going on here.  I have even added print sys.path to both py.test and the test program above and found that the paths are identical with the exception of the execute directory, /Users/esammons for the test.py and /usr/local/bin for py.test.

To further rule out issues I copied /usr/local/bin/py.test and /usr/local/bin/py.test-2.7 to my project root, same error occurred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused by the formatting of my values in my cfg file.   I'm using ConfigParser to parse my config file; the cfg file has the following format.

```
[DEFAULT]
key = value
key2 = value
key3 = value
```

The issue was caused by my wrapping the value in quotes ('value').  Specifically:

WRONG

```
bugzilla_url = 'https://bugzilla.example.com/xmlrpc.cgi'
```

RIGHT

```
bugzilla_url = https://bugzilla.example.com/xmlrpc.cgi
```

Comment: Same happened to me using Jenkins and [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)